# Use DirectorySearcher to find members of a distribution list in another domain using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I am using the below code to query AD. Our company has 2 domains:

1. `DC=one,DC=ad,DC=example1,DC=com` (`one.ad.example1.com`)
2. `DC=two,DC=example2,DC=com` (`two.example2.com`)

And:

- Both domains have users
- The 1st one (`one.ad.example1.com`) has a distribution list: `CN=distro,OU=DLs,OU=groups,DC=one,DC=ad,DC=example1,DC=com`

  - The DL has users from both domains in it

I **can** find the users in the first domain (`one.ad.example1.com`) by querying the first domain (`one.ad.example1.com`) for members of the DL that is in the first domain (`one.ad.example1.com`):

```
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=one,DC=ad,DC=example1,DC=com")
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
# $objSearcher.ReferralChasing = "All"
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange("distinguishedName".Split(","))

$objSearcher.Filter = "(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=distro,OU=DLs,OU=groups,DC=one,DC=ad,DC=example1,DC=com)"
$objSearcher.FindAll()
```

But I **cannot** find the users in the second domain (`two.example2.com`) by querying the second domain (`two.example2.com`) for members of the DL that is in the first domain (`one.ad.example1.com`):

```
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=two,DC=example2,DC=com")
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
# $objSearcher.ReferralChasing = "All"
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange("distinguishedName".Split(","))

$objSearcher.Filter = "(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=distro,OU=DLs,OU=groups,DC=one,DC=ad,DC=example1,DC=com)"
$objSearcher.FindAll()
```

What am I doing wrong? I cannot make two calls. I need to find users in the 2nd domain that are members of a DL that is in the 1st domain. How can I do that?

Comment: "I cannot make two calls" is a requirement. Yes, they are two trusted domains.

Answer (score 0):

If the two domains are part of the same AD forest, then you can solve this very simply by using the Global Catalog, which will return objects from all domains in the forest. That's as easy as using 'GC://' in the LDAP path instead of 'LDAP://`:

```
$objDomain = New-Object [adsi]"GC://DC=one,DC=ad,DC=example1,DC=com"
```

(`[adsi]` is a [type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_accelerators) for `DirectoryEntry`)

If the domains are not in the same AD forest, but just have a trust between them, then it's a little more tricky, but still doable of course. First, don't search. Just list the `member` attribute of the group itself. The tricky part will be the members on the other domain. The `member` attribute does not contain a direct reference to the object on the other domain. Instead, it uses a special object on the same domain of the group called a Foreign Security Principal (in a container called `ForeignSecurityPrincipals` at the root of the domain). The name of this object is the SID of the object on the other domain.

If you are running this from a computer that is joined to one of these domains, then you can use the SID notation to bind directly to the object on the other domain (`LDAP://<SID=XXXX>`).

```
$group = [adsi]"LDAP://CN=distro,OU=DLs,OU=groups,DC=one,DC=ad,DC=example1,DC=com"
$group.RefreshCache("member")
foreach ($member in $group.Member) {
    If ($member.StartsWith("CN=S-1-")) {
        $user = [adsi]"LDAP://<SID=$($member.Substring(3, $member.IndexOf(",CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,")-3))>"
    } else {
        $user = [adsi]"LDAP://$member"
    }
    # Do something with $user
}
```

If it can't find the object, you may have to hardcode the domain to tell it where to look:

```
$user = [adsi]"LDAP://example2.com/<SID=$($member.Substring(3, $member.IndexOf(",CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,")-3))>"
```